# Couchbase to Postgres two way sync

Tags: postgresql, couchbase, offline, couchbase-lite, offline-storage

I have a monolith Postgres database that contains all of my orgs data. We are creating a new offline mobile app that contains subset of this data that can be edited, added, removed by users while they are offline. There is a fair amount of images that can be uploaded/downloaded as well. To manage this and the offline sync I am leaning towards Couchbase Enterprise with offline sync support. What are my options when it comes to syncing the Couchbase data with my Postgres ? It needs to be two way. I do see Kafka connectors for Couchbase, can this be utilized ? Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options for sync. Here are a few:

- Kafka is certainly an option. [Couchbase has Kafka connector support](https://docs.couchbase.com/kafka-connector/current/quickstart.html) as both a sink and a source.
- Molo17 offers a tool called [GlueSync](https://molo17.com/gluesync/), which is automatic two-way sync between relational and Couchbase. They've built stuff specifically with mobile in mind as well, which sounds exactly like what you want.
- [Dataworkz](https://www.dataworkz.com/new-use-cases/) offers sync between relational and Couchbase. They can also provide structure changes to better take advantage of JSON in Couchbase (e.g. embedding/denormalization).